# What is and how do I remove the parenthesised number at the end of a web site project's name?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, vs-web-site-project

I created a web site - lets call it 'AjaxAir' and then decided to create the same site in a different location. I completely deleted anything to do with the first location, and created the same site elsewhere, but VS2012 U3 named the second site 'AjaxAir (2)'. I could find no project property specifying the '(2)', and when I tried again, I got a '(3)'.

Why is the web site being numbered when no other instance of it exists, and how do I remove the '(3)' from the current site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had this problem before

if you are using windows 7 open the following folder:

C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects

and there you will see the AjaxAir, AjaxAir (2), AjaxAir (3) along with their "sln" and "suo"

just move them to another location and when you open another website it will be "AjaxAir" again